# Is there a way to programmatically create aliased providers and AWS resources in other regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have AWS resources in many regions.

Most AWS resources don't have "region" parameter which means I need to do this and use `provider=aws.alias`:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias               = "us-east-1"
  region              = "us-east-1"
  allowed_account_ids = ["123456789"]
}

provider "aws" {
  alias               = "us-east-2"
  region              = "us-east-2"
  allowed_account_ids = ["123456789"]
}

... etc
```

It's a lot of boilerplate I need to duplicate in all my workspaces.

And I can't find a way to for_each over all provider aliases to create resources. Some resources I'll always need in all my regions. I have to manually write them all out 8 times for each region even though the config is identical!

Is there a feature that makes this better? Is there a way to programmatically create aliases or some way to dynamically change to a different region without creating all these provider configs manually?

Comment: There is currently no way to do it. If you want to do this programmatically, you need to generate the providers with code. You could use any general purpose programming language to iterate through the regions and generate the blocks.

Comment: well yeah I could "compile to terraform" but thats obviously awful. are there plans to make providers interpolatable in resources? or to change the aws provider to support region per resources?

Comment: `for_each` is coming for modules in the 0.13 release, but not not sure about the plans for providers. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17519